# "First ever car" or "first-ever car"? "Second best writer" or "second-best writer"?

Tags: hyphenation

Do these two sentences need to be hyphenated? It seems to me that "*ever*" doesn't really act as an adjective to "*car*," but I could be wrong.

> "*That was my first-ever car.*"

And

> "*She's the second-best writer I know.*"

My research show both the "*first ever*" and "*first-ever*," but it doesn't say if it's style. If anyone is more familiar with hyphens, I would like this to get claraffied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen both "first-ever" and "first ever" used, but I believe the latter is more common (or you could always say "my first car ever" and get around using it). 
Second-best is usually hyphenated when used as an adjective.

Comment: Hello, Lemon Tea. As MετάEd has said, "A good answer is comprehensive and contains evidence showing why it is correct. Links to external resources are encouraged. Answers which consist of virtually nothing but an unsupported statement or a citation are not useful and may be subject to deletion – even correct answers. For help writing a good answer, see _How to Answer_." Though here, the question is merely about basic research.